# Jquery: read a div containing html encoded json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to read in data in a bunch of in-page divs and use a plugin to pretty-print them:

```
$(".entries").each(function(){
    var input = $(this).text();
    $(this).JSONView(input, { collapsed: true });
});
```

and it all works nicely until I've got JSON that includes html encoded data, like this:

```
{ "0001" : { "size" : "16mo (6 1/2&quot;)", } }
```

Jquery's .text() and .html(), are converting the the html entity `&quot;` in the source to a real " and the string is not valid json for the next step.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried JSON.stringify({ "0001" : { "size" : "16mo (6 1/2&quot;)", } })?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery